# Revisions missing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

None of my revisions are displayed anymore in Tortoise SVN.  Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

When I right click on a folder and select show log; all as I see is the most recent revision in the bottom window i.e. there is nothing in the top window.

Answer (score 2):

It's a 3-pane window, and the splitter between the top 2 panes has been pushed all the way up to the top. Put your mouse over that thick bar right under "revision" and the cursor will switch to a horizontal bar with arrows above and below (if you're using default mouse cursors, anyway). Click there and pull down.